# OpenGL NDC and coordinates

Tags: opengl, glsl, coordinates, perspectivecamera

Although I am relatively new to OpenGL, I have no trouble with matrix algebra, homogeneous coordinates, rotations and projections. I have set up my mvp matrix to get a good view of a cube and it renders nicely.

Next, instead of rendering the cube, I am trying to read the color from a [background image](https://forums.artrage.com/attachment.php?attachmentid=3898&stc=1&thumb=1&d=1211248256). As expected, the texture is rendered clipped to where the cube is, but for some reason there is quite some distortion. (As per suggestion in the comments I am now dividing by `w` [thought OpenGL did this].)

As far as I understand, the `xy` coordinates in NDC should map linearly onto the window. Where does the distortion come from?

#### Vertex shader:

```
#version 330
uniform mat4 Mvp;

in vec3 in_shape;

out vec2 v_ndc;

void main() {
    gl_Position = Mvp * vec4(in_shape, 1.0);
    v_ndc = vec2(
        gl_Position.x / gl_Position.w,
        -gl_Position.y / gl_Position.w
    ) / 2 + 0.5;
}
```

#### Fragment shader:

```
#version 330
uniform sampler2D Background;

in vec2 v_ndc;

out vec4 f_color;

void main() {
    f_color = vec4(texture(Background, v_ndc).rgb, 1.0);
}
```

#### Result

[image]

Comment: NDC would be `gl_Position.xy/gl_Position.w`. `gl_Position.xy` is clipspace

Comment: Thanks, the scale is now right (I thought OpenGL did the division). Nevertheless, there is still distortion. I've updated the question and posted the new image.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

> As far as I understand, the xy coordinates in NDC should map linearly onto the window. Where does the distortion come from?

[`gl_Position`](https://www.khronos.org/registry/OpenGL-Refpages/gl4/html/gl_Position.xhtml) is a [Homogeneous coordinate](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Homogeneous_coordinate) you have to do a [Perspective divide](https://www.khronos.org/opengl/wiki/Vertex_Post-Processing#Perspective_divide)

```
v_ndc = gl_Position.xy/gl_Position.w
```

Note, `gl_Position.xy` is the clipspace coordiante. The coordinates in the clip space are transformed to the normalized device coordinates (NDC) in the range (-1, -1, -1) to (1, 1, 1) by dividing with the `w` component of the clip coordinates.

> There is still distortion.

This is because the interpolation of `v ndc` is done in the perspective. It is based on the [Barycentric coordinates](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Barycentric_coordinate_system) of the triangle primitive, which is defined by `gl_Position` in the perspective.

Use [`noperspective`](https://www.khronos.org/opengl/wiki/Type_Qualifier_(GLSL)) to do a linearly interpolated in window-space:

Vertex shader:

```
noperspective out vec2 v_ndc;
```

Fragment shader

```
noperspective in vec2 v_ndc;
```

See also [OpenGL Interpolation Qualifiers (GLSL)](http://www.geeks3d.com/20130514/opengl-interpolation-qualifiers-glsl-tutorial/)

Comment: So even though the `v_ndc` is 2D, its interpolation is still done in perspective. Thanks!

Comment: @Paul: Yes. The reason, why interpolation by default is in perspective, is, that the "original" application for textures was to apply them like "decals" to the objects being drawn. And for this to work without appearing "distorted" a perspective correct interpolation has to be applied to the texture coordinates. Obviously if you want the project the texture in screen space this is the opposite of what's desired. Interesting tidbid. The earliest 3D graphics chips (last century) couldn't do perspective correct texturing and without that things looked weird.